# Как назвать единицу оказанного сервиса на английском?

Tags: терминология

Добрый день, делаю небольшой сайт-сервис куда пользователи загружают свои документы и получают его в обработанном виде. Не могу придумать как правильно назвать такую сущность как результат выполнения заказа. Product - больше подходит для физических товаров, а order - это фиксация факта заказа, а не результат выполнения. буду благодарен заподсказки

Comment: Order result...

Comment: transformation, doc in, doc out